# Jasmine saying variable is undefined, when it gets defined in a function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my `sp.js`:

```
angular.module("SpPageApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        self.add = function() {
            BaseService.add.sp(self.sp, function() {
                self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

and this is my `test_sp.js`:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {
    var ctrl, mockBaseService;

    beforeEach(function() {

        mockBaseService = {
            spls: 'x',
            cerrorMessages: 'y',
            add: { sp: function(something, cb) { cb() } },
            fetch: { selfsps: function(cb) { cb() } },
            logout: function() {},
        };


        module('BaseApp', function($provide) {
            $provide.value('BaseService', mockBaseService);
        });

        module('SpPageApp');

        inject(function($controller) {
            ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            });
        });


    });

     it('add() calls through to BaseService.add.sp.', function() {
         ctrl.sp = "{'spName': 'test post'}"
         spyOn(mockBaseService.add, 'sp');
         ctrl.add();
         expect(mockBaseService.add.sp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ctrl.sp, jasmine.any(Function));
         expect(ctrl.cerrorMessages).toBe(mockBaseService.cerrorMessages);
     });   
});
```

When I test the code by doing `karma start`, it raises this error:

```
Expected undefined to be 'y'.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/a/Documents/CMS/CMSApp/static/js/karma/tests/test_sp.js:53:38)
```

and points to the line:

```
expect(ctrl.cerrorMessages).toBe(mockBaseService.cerrorMessages);
```

How vome it is saying that `ctrl.cerrorMessages` is undefined even though, right after `ctrl.add()` is executed, it gets defined in the callback of `BaseService.add.sp()` like so:

```
self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
```

? I tried initializing the variable at the start of the controller like so:

```
self.cerrorMessages;
```

but that also didn't work (same error was raised).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to call through so that actual method is called

```
spyOn(mockBaseService.add, 'sp').and.callThrough();
```

Comment: oh okay, so basically, if I don't add `and.callThrough()` when spying on a function, then if the function is called, it won't execute the actual functions code?